# in progress bar completed then redirect on page to another page through to javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**My Question:**
I have developing Mvc application in this application i have `profiling.cshtml` page.

1. In that page i have put the progress bar link n that progress bar complete that process after that redirect to another page which name is `recommendedportfolio.cshtml`
2. I m facing the problem in javascript that not work properly.
   4 In javascript which i return the window.locate is not redirect the that page

**My code:**

```
<div>
                    @Html.ActionLink("PROFILING . . .", "recommendedportfolio", "Home", null, new { @class = " process progress-label ;", @Target = "_self", @onclick = " data()", @id = "Prog" })
                       </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>             
            function data() {
                debugger;
                window.open = "http://localhost:2303/Home/recommendedportfolio";
                   }
         </script>
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what difficulty you are facing in javascript. Please modify your question a bit and repost it again.

Comment: in java sciprt not going to another page which i loacted